# I do not know what the board is. Can someone please help

Tags: arduino-pro-micro

[image]

It says that it is a pro micro, but I have searched the arduino website and i cannot find something that looks like this or is called this.

Comment: Sparkfun created a minimal version of the Arduino micro board and called it the pro micro. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12640 Perhaps you can use it as a normal arduino micro board (with a few missing pins) or install the Sparkfun boards. With this cheap board, you don't know what kind of bootloader it has.

Comment: If the chip is an ATmega 32u4 I would guess a cheap clone of the Sparkfun Pro Micro

Comment: @Jot It plugged it in and it is reading it as an Arduino Leonardo

Comment: That is the same. The arduino micro is a minimal Leonardo and the pro micro is a minimal micro. I don't know if they all share the same bootloader. Use a picture of the pinmapping https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/pro-micro--fio-v3-hookup-guide/hardware-overview-pro-micro  and you can use it as a leonardo as well. The leds can also be used (with limitations). The 3.3v/8MHz version is slower than the 16MHz Leonardo. Since "j1" is not soldered in your photo, I assume that you have a 3.3v/8MHz version.

Comment: Oops, I see a 16MHz x-tal. Maybe you should solder jumper "j1" to make it run at 5v.

Comment: I got it, just it is now not showing up on my com ports now but it was before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Arduino compatible board don't have to look like one in Arduino web site.
There are many clones and custom boards are available. 
Since it says pro micro, choose `Pro micro` from bard option and try uploading some code.

Comment: By default there is no Pro Micro support in the IDE. It needs to be installed.

Comment: As far as i can remember, Arduino IDE has by default support for pro micro. Even it doesn't, Leonardo has default support on arduino IDE. Which can also be choosed to program this board for testing.